# OAuth2 redirect doesn`t work as it should

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, token, access-token

I am working with OAuth2 and have some issues. I know there is a lot of posts about this topic, I have read most of them but still did not found answer to my issues. Sorry for bad English, I will do my best.

How do I bypass OAuth2 approval dialogue? If I get it right, when user first time approve permissions, google should next time automatically redirect user to my redirect url. In my case, when I restart session(delete cookies) and go to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fauth&response_type=code&client_id=myClientId&state=myState&scope=myScopes` I get approval dialogue again asking for offline access approval (assuming my app already have other permissions). When I approve it and go to this url again it works fine(redirect me to redirect url without asking for offline access). But when I restart session I am asked for offline access again. Why? I do not have neither `access_type=offline` or `approval_prompt=force` parameter set. Am I missing something?

Comment: The docs are correct, you don't need `access` or `id token` for refreshing. You didn't post any code, are you sure the "invalid request" error is from the refreshing request and not from a request you're making to a service?

Comment: I believe so. Code is added. I create request, set method to post, set parameters, and send it. As specified in documentation, thought

Comment: I removed code and first part of question becouse I found solution.

Comment: for this other problem, I'm not sure if you are using a library or not, but if the auth screen is asking for offline access permission, it's because access type is being set to offline... you can try adding this to the url (these are supposed to be the default values, though): &access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto

Comment: also, for some APIs (like youtube), if the user has multiple identities (like multiple YT channels) the auth page will always ask the user to select which one he wants to use, so it will not be an automatic redirect to your page

Comment: I don`t use library. Adding &access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto to url also didn`t help. It`s weird because even if I use browser I get this approval dialogue and then when I approve it, it works fine. I use YT api also but I am testing with my account with only one channel and even if I delete YT scopes doesn`t help.

Comment: If you found a solution, would you be kind and post it as an answer?

Comment: sure. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: probably problem is that google save some offline access data in cookies so when you delete it, google prompt for offline access again. Just guessing..